# Bluetooth callbacks preventing collectionView cellforitem function from being called

Tags: bluetooth, collectionview

I believe bluetooth callbacks are preventing the collectionView cellForItem function from being called, although I don't have evidence for that.

Here is the relevant bluetooth code:

```
   func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                    advertisementData: [String: Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    

    guard RSSI.intValue >= -150
        else {
            os_log("Discovered perhiperal not in expected range, at %d", RSSI.intValue)
            return
    }
    
    var detectedServiceCBUuids = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey] as? [CBUUID] ?? []
    if let detectedOverflowCBUuids = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataOverflowServiceUUIDsKey] as? [CBUUID] {
        detectedServiceCBUuids.append(contentsOf: detectedOverflowCBUuids)
    }
    for detectedServiceCBUuid in detectedServiceCBUuids {
        print("I detected serviceUuid: \(detectedServiceCBUuid.uuidString)")
        for discoverableCBUUID in discoverableCBUUIDS {
            if discoverableCBUUID == detectedServiceCBUuid {
                print("We have a CBUUID match between detected and discoverable")
                if self.detectedCBUUIDs.contains(detectedServiceCBUuid){
                    return
                }
                self.detectedCBUUIDs.append(detectedServiceCBUuid)
                print("self.detectedCBUUIDs count is ", self.detectedCBUUIDs.count)
                print("the array is now like this: ", self.detectedCBUUIDs)
                centralManager.stopScan()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
                
            }
        }
        
       
    }

    if discoveredPeripheral != peripheral {

        discoveredPeripheral = peripheral

        os_log("Connecting to perhiperal %@", peripheral)
        centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant collectionView code:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
   
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell

    if users.count != 0 {

        print("users count is not 0, so checking if detectedCBUUIDs is 0...")

        if self.detectedCBUUIDs.count != 0 {

            print("detectedCBUUIDs is not 0, so finding the matched user...")

            for user in users {

                print("trying user named ", user.name)

                if let userUUID = user.userUUID() {
                    let userCBUUID = CBUUID(string: userUUID)
                    print("potential match CBUUID is ", userCBUUID)
                    print("detected CBUUID is ", self.detectedCBUUIDs[indexPath.item])

                    if userCBUUID == self.detectedCBUUIDs[indexPath.item]{
                        if let name = user.userName(), let uuid = user.userUUID(), let profileImageUrl = user.userProfileImageUrl() {
                            print("user name is ", user.name)
                            cell.titleLabel.text = user.name
                            cell.userProfileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString( profileImageUrl)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                            }
                            return cell
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }

    cell.titleLabel.text = self.broadcastCBUUID.uuidString
    cell.titleLabel.text = "No Discoverable Friends"
    return cell
}
```

I'm trying to discover a CBUUID using bluetooth, and then use it to identify a user and display that user in the collectionView.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would set two breakpoints in XCode to figure out what is going on.  (1) on `self.collectionView.reloadData()` (2) in `override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`  Do both breakpoints get hit after discovering the peripheral of interest?

Comment: I did as you suggested and only the self.collectionView.reloadData() breakpoint gets hit.

Comment: You should also have methods like `numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView)` and `collectionView(_ collectionView:  numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int` which must return the number of sections and items in each section.  Do each of these methods get called, and do they each return a non-zero value?

Comment: Neither get called!

Comment: Then I suspect that (a) the UICollectionView is never added to the parent view or (b) the data source is never set on the collection view like this: `collectionView.dataSource = self`  If you think you are doing these things, you probably need to that setup code.